# Creating Set of sequences(12345678)

Tags: c#

I would like to create set of strings and below is the only limitation.
Same digit should not repeat.

string Range 1-8(12345678) or 1-16(12345678910111213141516)
For example:(set of series)

```
12345678
12345687
12345876
12345867
...
...
87654321
```

Like that 2^8(1-8) and 2^16(1-16) possibilities are there.
How can i generate these strings very efficiently with less computation?

Comment: What is this for? Work or learning (including homework)? Also, have you tried anything?

Comment: I am trying to create some kind of index based compression.In the above series each number denotes the value position(8,7,4).

Comment: Aren't these `P(n,k)` and not `2^n`?  So `P(8,8) == 8! == 40,320` and `P(16,16) == 16! == 20,922,789,888,000` possibilities.

Comment: P(8,8) == 8! == 40,320 and P(16,16) == 16! == 20,922,789,888,000 .This not possible.

Comment: Do they have to appear in a lexicographical order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 8 case is possible but you will quickly run out of space after that.

This is not a `2^n` case like you think it is -- it's an `n!` case.

For 8, there will be 40,320 permutations.

```
permute(k,n) = k! / (n-k)!
permute(8,8) = 8! / (8-8)! = 8! = 40320
```

For 16, there will be 20,922,789,888,000 permutations.  At 16 bytes / permutation, you'll need about 304TB to store them.

@kol's answer should do the permutations for you but I think you need to change your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, you need to [generate all permutations of a given set of symbols (in your case, digits)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G).